# Can't get json parameter to Jersey @POST / GET

Tags: java, jquery, html, json, post

We are using dynamic web app with jersey, the client is android mobile using phonegap jQuery and Javascript.

When the user is sending a post to the web server, it is getting the request but doesn't see any parameters (the @Counsume).

I know that the jersey is working because when I tried to use @get method on other function it worked fine.

This is my code:

//web server

```
 package il.ac.hit;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.ws.rs.*;
    @Path("/TakeAHikeDao")
    public class TakeAHikeDao
    {
        @POST
        @Path("userCredentialsValidate")
        @Consumes("application/json")
        @Produces("application/text")
        public String userCredentialsValidate(Map<String, String> userCredentials)
        {
            System.out.println(userCredentials.toString()+"%%%");
            return ("{\"status\":\"success\"}");    
        }
    }
```

//web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TakeAHikeServerSide</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>il.ac.hit</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

//client html with javascript code

```
<script language="JavaScript" charset="utf-8>
function checkUser() 
{

var url=localhost:8080/rest/TakeAHikeDao/userCredentialsValidate

$.post("url",{"username":"dan","password":"123456"},function( data ) {
        alert( "JSON Data: " + data);
        });

/*  this is the second option we tried
    $.get("url",{"username":"dan","password":"123456"},function( data ) {
        alert( "JSON Data: " + data);
        });
*/

 /* this is the third option we tried       
    $.getJSON("url",{"username":"dan","password":"123456"},function( data ) {
            alert( "JSON Data: " + data);
            });
 */
}
</script>

//this is the button calling the function.
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" onClick="checkUser()">SUBMIT</a>
```

The output that I recieved in the console from the the method:

```
System.out.println(userCredentials.toString()+"%%%");
```

is "%%%" (the userCredentials is empty and not getting the data that was send).

Thanks in advance,
ofir.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your method signature to take instead strongly typed parameter names rather than the generic parameter?

Comment: hi Daimian, thanks for the answer but i don't know what you mean by changing the method signature to take strongly typed parameter names. i will appreciate if you could be more specific.

Comment: public String userCredentialsValidate(String username,String password)

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to say that i've found the problem,
The Changes are on the consumes:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
MultiValuedMap<String, String> userCredentials

@POST
@Path("userCredentialsValidate")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
public String userCredentialsValidate(MultiValuedMap<String, String> userCredentials)
{
        System.out.println(userCredentials.toString()+"%%%");
        return ("{\"status\":\"success\"}");
}
```

i Hope this will help you.